# powershell for each file build a string to execute

Tags: java, string, powershell, foreach, filenames

I need to schedule a windows job to loop thru thousand of files and execute a command with the command options, the file name, and extension.

These files have an extension of *.xls in directory c:\proj.  For example, one of the file is myImportantFile0001.xls, I would execute the following in powershell, manually:

```
PS> java.exe -classpath  "C:\PROGRA~2\my1.0.2\lib/*" com.my.madsci  -v --collector-url https://api.fun.my.com/ --oauth-url  https://api.my.com/oauth/access    --type   /fileName:string/discovery:string  --key  /fileName:"myImportantFile0001/discovery:discovery" "C:\proj\myImportantFile0001_xls.txt"
```

couple of problems I've got are:

the command itself has double quotes,
 the file name and extensions need to be found and converted
 execute a java within powershell

So how can I loop thru the thousand of files to build a string to execute the command using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

does below script helps you? i think it just strings combination.

```
$Commands = ls C:\Temp\*.xlsx | %{
"java.exe -classpath `"C:\PROGRA~2\my1.0.2\lib/*`" com.my.madsci -v --collector-url https://api.fun.my.com/ --oauth-url https://api.my.com/oauth/access --type /fileName:string/discovery:string --key /fileName:`"$($_.BaseName)/discovery:discovery`" `"C:\proj\$($_.BaseName)_xls.txt`""
}

$Commands

exit # remove the line if you want to execute

$Commands | %{
& $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
PS> ls C:\Temp\*.xlsx | foreach-object {  
    "java.exe -classpath `"C:\PROGRA~2\my1.0.2\lib/*`" com.my.madsci -v --collector-url https://api.fun.my.com/ --oauth-url https://api.my.com/oauth/access --type /fileName:string/discovery:string --key /fileName:`"$($_.name)/discovery:discovery`" `"C:\proj\$($_.name)_xls.txt`""
}
```

Comment: thanks.  well, the ls may work but doesn't because the fileName section still have the extension of the file. which is needed to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" -Filter "*.xls"
foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    $command = "java.exe -classpath  ""C:\PROGRA~2\my1.0.2\lib/*"" com.my.madsci  "
    $command = $command + "-v --collector-url https://api.fun.my.com/ "
    $command = $command + "--oauth-url  https://api.my.com/oauth/access    "
    $command = $command + "--type   /fileName:string/discovery:string  "
    $command = $command + ("--key  /fileName:""{0}/discovery:discovery"" " -f $file.BaseName)
    $command = $command + ("""C:\proj\{0}_xls.txt""" -f $file.BaseName)
    Invoke-Expression $command
}
```

Comment: I like your programming style.  It is a joy to read and to understand.  Yes, your code work and "$file.BaseName" was hard to find.

Comment: for beginner doing a bit of powershell with OS related automation, which book/resource would you recommend?

Comment: Thank you workaholic, blushing right now :-).
A good starting point for the absolute beginner is the book "Learn Windows PowerShell 3 in a Month of Lunches", more references of good books can be found here: http://powershell.org/wp/2012/04/21/powershell-book-recommendations/.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can also schedule it from powershell itself (Works with PS 3.0 and above)

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "9:00 AM"
$scriptPath = "C:\FilePath\myScript.ps1"
Register-ScheduledJob -Name "MyJob" -FilePath $scriptPath -Trigger $trigger
```